# Get data with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm learning Python and my first project is get data from NFL site using Selenium.
I had some problems with the loop to add the data and click on the next button until the end.
The error message that appears is this:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method": "xpath", "selector": "// * [@ title =" Next Page "]"}
(Session info: chrome = 89.0.4389.114)

Also, I don't know if this code will add data to my data frame.
What did i do wrong or what is missing?

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import json
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


colunas =['Player','Pass Yds','Yds/Att','Att','Cmp','TD','INT','Rate','1st','1st%','20+','40+','Lng','Sck','SckY']
qb=pd.DataFrame()


url = "https://www.nfl.com/stats/player-stats/"
option = Options
option.headless= True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

next_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Next Page"]')

while True:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='d3-o-table--horizontal-scroll']//table")
    html_content = element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
    time.sleep(3)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,'html.parser')
    table = soup.find(name='table')

    df_full = pd.read_html( str(table))[0]

    df1= df_full[['Player','Pass Yds','Yds/Att','Att','Cmp','TD','INT','Rate','1st','1st%','20+','40+','Lng','Sck','SckY']]
    qb = pd.concat([df1])

    try:
        next_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Next Page"]')
        next_link.click()

    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        break

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things to correct

1. Add error handling for `NoSuchElementException` and break the loop.
2. You should concat the captured table data with existing dataframe `qb = pd.concat([qb, df1])`
3. Options should be instantiated `option = Options()`. Parenthesis is required
4. If you want to run the code in headless mode pass the options in `webdriver.chrome(executable_path='<WEB_DRIVER_PATH>', chrome_options=option)`

So here is the code after making all the above changes

```
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import json
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException


colunas =['Player','Pass Yds','Yds/Att','Att','Cmp','TD','INT','Rate','1st','1st%','20+','40+','Lng','Sck','SckY']
qb=pd.DataFrame()


url = "https://www.nfl.com/stats/player-stats/"
option = Options() # you need a instance of Options so Options() parenthesis missed in your code
option.headless= True # looks like you wanted to run it in headless mode but didn't use it
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=option)
driver.get(url)

# this is not required here
# next_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Next Page"]')

while True:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='d3-o-table--horizontal-scroll']//table")
    html_content = element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
    time.sleep(3)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,'html.parser')
    table = soup.find(name='table')

    df_full = pd.read_html( str(table))[0]

    df1= df_full[['Player','Pass Yds','Yds/Att','Att','Cmp','TD','INT','Rate','1st','1st%','20+','40+','Lng','Sck','SckY']]
    qb = pd.concat([qb, df1]) # concat with existing data frame qb

    try:
        next_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Next Page"]')
        next_link.click()
    
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break

    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        break

# just to make sure captured the data correctly
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', qb.shape[1]):
    print(qb)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    next_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Next Page"]')
    next_link.click()

except NoSuchElementException:
    break
```

Just catch the error and break.

Import

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```